# Translate Excel header fields

Tags: .net, angular

I have an Excel file being generated. I got this endpoint Export, which is called on my Angular app by export().
There is a need to translate the header fields that are from "ANIMAL" to another language.
My response object is a list of ANIMAL with fields from the object itself, mapped to the data coming from the database.
How can I archieve the translation of this header fields?

Here is my code:

```
  [HttpPost]
  [EnableCors("AllowSpecificOrigins")]
  [Produces("text/csv")]
  public async Task<IActionResult> Export([FromBody] REQUEST request, CancellationToken cancellationToken = default)
  {
      IEnumerable<ANIMAL> response = await Service.ExportAsync(request, cancellationToken);
     
      return Ok(response);
  }
```

```
export() {
    this.service.export(REQUEST).subscribe({
      next: blob => {
        saveAs(blob, '_export_' + new Date().toLocaleDateString() + '_' + new Date().toLocaleTimeString() + '.csv');
      },
      error: error => {
       console.log('Error');
      }
    });
  }
```

Comment: very confusing... Export seems to be returning IEnumerable<ANIMAL>... but you're typing it to blob and saving it as a CSV file?  Where does Excel come into this? What is "ANIMAL", and what are these "header fields".  Maybe include code that defines ANIMAL?